# Manual square root method explained

Tags: proof-explanation, radicals

I was investigating some methods of computing square roots by hand and I found a certain script which presents the following method of computing:

NOTE: the following notation represents positional notation of a number, e.g. $$\overline{ab} = 10a + b$$

The algorithm is presented with an example of a square of a 4-digit number:

$$\overline{abcd}^2 = (10^3a + 10^2b + 10c + d)$$
$$= a^210^6 + b^210^4 +c^210^2 + d^2 + 2ab10^5 + 2ac10^4 +2ad10^3 + 2bc10^3 + 2bd10^2 +2cd10$$
$$= a^2 \cdot 10^6 + b \cdot 10^4 \cdot (2a \cdot 10 + b) + c \cdot 10^2(2 \cdot (10a + b) \cdot 10 + c) + d(2 \cdot (a \cdot 10^2 + b \cdot 10 + c) \cdot 10 + d)$$
$$= a^2 \cdot 10^6 + \overline{(2a)b} \cdot b \cdot 10^4 + \overline{(2\overline{ab})c} \cdot c \cdot 10^2 + \overline{(2\overline{abc})d} \cdot d$$

The final equality is used in the algorithm. Now it is shown on the example of $\sqrt{14175225}$:

$$14175225 = 9 \cdot 10^6 + 5175225$$
$$= 9 \cdot 10^6 + 67 \cdot 7 \cdot 10^4 + 485225$$
$$= 9 \cdot 10^6 + 67 \cdot 7 \cdot 10^4 + 746 \cdot 6 \cdot 10^2 + 37625$$
$$= 9 \cdot 10^6 + 67 \cdot 7 \cdot 10^4 + 746 \cdot 6 \cdot 10^2 + 7525 \cdot 5$$
$$= 3765^2$$

So the process basically finds the numbers $a,b,c,d$ so they satisfy the final equality. Now there is no other explanation for this, for example the author just says that $a = 3$ with no further logic behind it. Why couldn't it be $a=2$ for example? How can one know at the start that $a = 3$ and then continue the process by simply knowing it will satisfy the equation? Also how can we know that a number such as $14175225$ will have a 4-digit square root?

None of these things are explained in the script so I would like an explanation if someone has any insight into this.

Answer (score 2):

> the author just says that *a*=3 with no further logic behind it.
>     Why couldn't it be *a*=2 for example?

Pairing from the implied decimal point, the number is "14 17 52 25".

The value of "*a*" is chosen as the largest digit whose square isn't greater than 14.

4×4 is 16, which is too big, but 3×3 is 9, which fits, so *a* = 3.

If someone simply asked you what the square root of 14 million is, you'd likely think that 4000 is slightly too big and 3000 is a lot too small, so you'd reply something like "in the high 3000s".